# XML urn:# is not a valid value for anyURI

Tags: xml, xsd

I am having some troubles on a wsdl file, which on SONIC Workbench is not accepted, while on Oracle JDev and SOAP UI is tolerated.
Basically the parser claims the following:

Exception:

org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'urn:#ApproveAccumulatedProvisioningRolesSoap' is not a valid value for 'anyURI'.

at org.wsi.xml.XMLUtils$ErrHandler.error(Unknown Source)
....

As far as I can understand the urn:# is the reason. Can anyone address me on where to find further informations on such syntax, eventually how I can fix it.

Thanks in advance.
Alessandro Ilardo

Comment: +1 for asking the same question I was about to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please observe that according to the [rfc2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), the colon character is reserved within the URI format. The SAXException that you are getting is a validation exception and it could be that Oracle JDev and SOAP UI skips validation of URIs while SONIC Workbench does not.

The hash (or sharp) character is a delimiter between a URI and a fragment, and is as such disallowed in the URI syntax. This could more likely be the reason for the validation exception. If you have access to the schema which the xml is validated against, I suggest you run your own validation with eg. [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) or a similar XML tool.

Comment: Weird. The suggestion @austincheney actually works -- despite what you wrote about the colon & the hash. Why?

Comment: @Daniel: The hash sign is a delimiter between the "absoluteURI" or "relativeURI" part and the "fragment" part of an URI (paraphrasing the section 4 of the RFC2396), so I'm guessing that the tools allow for an empty absolute/relative URI and validates the `#someThing` as a valid fragment part. What you are asking pertains to implementation behaviour, of which I know nothing. All I was referring was the spec :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
urn://#ApproveAccumulatedProvisioningRolesSoap
```

Comment: Wow! That indeed gets rid of the validation error. +1 for a concrete (and correct) solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use xjc compiler, you can add -nv attr to turn off strict validation of xsd scheme.